# Как передать значение переменной из одной функции в другую JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект, ширина которого равна заданному в инпуте значению и меняется в зависимости от значения:

```
document.querySelector('#input-width').addEventListener('input', width => { 
    if (width.target.value < 280 ) {
        document.querySelector('#square').style.width = width.target.value + 'px';
    } else if (width.target.value < 500) {
       document.querySelector('#square').style.width = width.target.value / 2 + 'px';
    } else {
       document.querySelector('#square').style.width = width.target.value / 10 + 'px';
   }
})
```

Есть объект, позиционирование которого задается значением из другого инпута относительно левого края и меняется в зависимости от размера первого объекта:

```
document.querySelector('#input-otverstie-x').addEventListener('input', kevt => {
    if (width.target.value < 280 ) {
        document.querySelector('#show-otverstie').style.left = kevt.target.value + 'px';
    } else if (width.target.value < 500) {
       document.querySelector('#show-otverstie').style.left = kevt.target.value / 2 + 'px';
    } else {
       document.querySelector('#show-otverstie').style.left = kevt.target.value / 10 + 'px';
   }
})
```

Но проблема в том, что в такой конструкции значение переменной width не передается во вторую функцию и условие не выполняется. Как можно правильно передать значение переменной?

Comment: `let width = document.getElementById('square').offsetWidth`

Comment: @Talleyran а в какую часть кода это нужно подставить?

Comment: Во втором лисенере просто всегда его получать и уже просто `width` пихать в условия

Comment: @Talleyran если честно, всё равно не понятно, как должен выглядеть второй лисенер при добавлении новой переменной, точнее куда конкретно её нужно добавить

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, объявить переменную в области, доступной для обеих функций

Comment: Пожалуйста старайтесь давать развёрнутые ответы. Постарайтесь дать куски кода, а ещё лучше минимальный воспроизводимый пример. Так же будет неплохо прикрепить ссылки на достоверные источники информации

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).